# MYSQL: procedure and trigger error

Tags: mysql, triggers, procedure

I'm rather new to MySQL and am encountering an error with my procedure, I want to be able to call the same thing for updates, inserts and deletes to a to my table so need a procedure to call.
I've looked at [MySQL Fire Trigger for both Insert and Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318224/mysql-fire-trigger-for-both-insert-and-update) and [The MySQL "DELIMITER" keyword isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300595/the-mysql-delimiter-keyword-isnt-working) as well as some other but nothing helped. (the delimiter keyword also doesnt work producing a sepperate error but that doesnt help) 
The error is this and I cant work out what it means:

"Error
SQL query:

```
-- trigger on work log change
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PROC_TRACK_CHANGES CREATE DEFINER = root@localhost PROCEDURE PROC_TRACK_CHANGES BEGIN INSERT INTO CHANGES( LoggedTimeStamp, EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp, ProposalID, WorkDone ) 
SELECT NOW( ) , EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp, ProposalID, WorkDone
FROM WORKLOG;
```

MySQL said:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE PROC_TRACK_CHANGES
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ' at line 3"

---

The errorred code in question is this:

```
CREATE TABLE WORKLOG(
EmployeeID              BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- FKEY PKEY
LogTimeStamp            TIMESTAMP, -- PKEY
ProposalID              BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- FKEY
WorkDone                VARCHAR(200),
CONSTRAINT WORKLOG_FOREIGN_KEY_EMP FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EmployeeID),
CONSTRAINT WORKLOG_FOREIGN_KEY_PRO FOREIGN KEY (ProposalID) REFERENCES PROPOSALS (ProposalID),
CONSTRAINT WORKLOG_PROPOSALS_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp)
);

CREATE TABLE CHANGES(
LoggedTimeStamp         TIMESTAMP, -- PKEY
EmployeeID              BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- FKEY
LogTimeStamp            TIMESTAMP, -- fkey
ProposalID              BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- FKEY
WorkDone                VARCHAR(200),
CONSTRAINT CHANGES_FOREIGN_KEY_EMP FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EmployeeID),
CONSTRAINT CHANGES_FOREIGN_KEY_PRO FOREIGN KEY (ProposalID) REFERENCES PROPOSALS (ProposalID),
CONSTRAINT CHANGES_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (LoggedTimeStamp)
);

-- trigger on work log change
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PROC_TRACK_CHANGES
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE PROC_TRACK_CHANGES
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CHANGES (LoggedTimeStamp, EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp, ProposalID, WorkDone)
    SELECT now(), EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp, ProposalID, WorkDone FROM WORKLOG;
END;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TR_WORKLOG_UPDATE
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER TR_WORKLOG_UPDATE
    BEFORE UPDATE ON 'WORKLOG'
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL PROC_TRACK_CHANGES();
END;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TR_WORKLOG_INSERT
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER TR_WORKLOG_INSERT BEFORE INSERT ON WORKLOG
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL PROC_TRACK_CHANGES();
END;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TR_WORKLOG_DELETE
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER TR_WORKLOG_DELETE BEFORE DELETE ON WORKLOG
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL PROC_TRACK_CHANGES();
END;
```

It's probably something simple that i'm missing but the MYSQL debugger confuses me.
many thanks!

Comment: A trigger drop is a single statement and a trigger create too. Seperate them with `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A procedure `drop` is a single statement and a procedure `create` too. Seperate them with the delimiter.

Another thing is that you need to define another delimiter than `;`. Otherwise the DB will termiante every statement at the `;` which makes some trigger and procedure definitions incomplete. So use for example

```
delimiter |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PROC_TRACK_CHANGES
|
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE PROC_TRACK_CHANGES
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CHANGES (LoggedTimeStamp, EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp, ProposalID, WorkDone)
    SELECT now(), EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp, ProposalID, WorkDone FROM WORKLOG;
END
|
```

Comment: The problem with delimiter is that i get the error "ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String" when i use it..

Comment: That is odd. How do you execute this?

Comment: I think it came from using multiple character delimiters such as '//' or '$$'...
now I'm getting a 'need super privilage error' which i assume means it works, i'm just not allowed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PROC_TRACK_CHANGES;
```

Notice the semi-colon at the end.

Comment: Thanks, i still get confused on syntax as to what is a single statement and what can span multi lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a temporary delimiter other than semi-colon, and use that delimiter at the end of both your `DROP PROCEDURE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements.

Also you need to add parentheses after the procedure name in the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement even if it takes no arguments.

This should work for you:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PROC_TRACK_CHANGES $$

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE PROC_TRACK_CHANGES ()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CHANGES (LoggedTimeStamp, EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp, ProposalID, WorkDone)
    SELECT now(), EmployeeID, LogTimeStamp, ProposalID, WorkDone FROM WORKLOG;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```